# Fastest Way to Get Similar Values in C# Dictionary

Tags: c#, algorithm, sorting, generics

I have a spatial hash class in C# to detect 3D Data. Each vertex position has a spatial hash and `Vector3` stored in a `Dictionary<float, Vector3>` where the float is the actual spatial hash I've calculated. The way I understand spatial hashes is that you sort the hashes into buckets and then get the values that are within at threshold (say, 0.0001f) of each other. Most research I have done has implemented bucket sorting, which I can't figure out how to implement with the `Dictionary` I have.

So, my question is, how should I approach getting similar values in a Dictionary like this? So far, it appears to me that I need to sort the hash values into buckets with the size of `threshold` and somehow maintain a link to the `Vector3`. Am I approaching this entirely the wrong way? Is there, say, a different generic that better suits this particular use case?

Comment: Are you sure it's Dictionary<Vector3, float> and not Dictionary<float, Vector3>? To me it seems that you're trying to sort by value and not by key.

Comment: Wow, you're right. Let me change that.

Answer (score 0):

Implement interface

```
IEqualityComparer<float>
```

to handle the fuzzy matching and pass it to the constructor of the Dictionary

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132151.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132072.aspx

Comment: I do not see how `IEqualityComparer` is going to match values that are not exact, but close to each other. It appears to me that the interface you gave me is going to only match exact values.

Comment: @user81572: The interface merely specifies that there's an `Equals()` to call. You can implement that `Equals()` to do a fuzzy comparison, and pass your fuzzy implementation to the `Dictionary` constructor, just like Moho says.

Comment: @MatthewWatson Oh, so he's saying that I should probably change that to check if the value is within the threshold? i.e. something like (pseudo code): `if (x == (x += 0.001f) || (x -= 0.001f)) return bothValues;`?

Comment: Implementing the Equals is simple enough, but the `GetHashCode` is not.  You need to ensure that all items that are equal due to the fuzzy logic have the same hash, but yet you need to minimize the number of non-equal items that share a hash.  If you just do something like `return 0` you may as well just use a `LinkedList`, because that's what you have.  In the general case (and in most practical cases) this is not a solvable problem.

Answer (score 0):

Please re-consider using the spacial hash if you're trying to avoid the hassle. While absolutely possible to implement, 3D hashing functions are quite complicated (if you want a perfect hash, that is) and can be easily replaced by some smart 'close-enough' functions.

So, the choice is yours:

[Perfect Hashing](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/hoppe/perfecthash.pdf)

or

[Smartly used 'Close-Enough' functions](http://oglsuperbible5.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/Src/GLTools/include/math3d.h) (taken from OpenGL SuperBible's source code, please look for 'm3dCloseEnough')

Comment: I've already got a pretty solid spatial hash, it's that I don't know the ins-and-outs of .NET and C# yet. I'm coming from C++ and all the things I'm used to from that. The question is really how I should best extract the similar hashes. i.e. If I have a hash that is x number, what is the best way to get the x +- 0.0001 or the `threshold`?

Comment: Well, if you had a solid hashing algorithm, you wouldn't be asking this question in the first place :) It's not a C# or C++ thing I'm afraid, it's about the hashing algorithm. Care to share its code?

Comment: Yeah, I'm fine with sharing code. The real problem isn't how I hash the Vector3 values, it's how I find the similar values. Basically the hash is stored as a float and the original Vector3 in the value part. So it ends up something like `Dictionary<float hash, Vector3 vertex>`. When I go to see which two vertices are close together, I see if the two hash values are `threshold` distance by comparing the hash and `threshold`. It's just beyond me for some reason to find a way to do this part.

Comment: If it does help, my actual hash is computed by taking the coordinates and running it through: `(x * p1) ^ (y * p2) ^ (z * p3) % _hashTable.Count` The p1, p2, and p3 are very large prime numbers and the _hashTable.Count is the number of elements in the dictionary.

Comment: What you're saying would be possible if a) you had integer-based space b) modified your hashing algorithm, because it's not perfect and *will* produce duplicates

Comment: Interesting question, though.

Comment: Why would you say the algorithm will produce duplicates? I have run it through a few times with 10K+ Vector3's and have yet to detect a duplicate. Also, what do you mean by integer-based space? I don't know how it would be possible to store the Vector3 float values as integers.

Comment: Well, this algorithm eventually will produce duplicates. If not for one set, then for another. You simply can't guarantee unique hashes based on it. To answer your second question - don't use floats at all. Use integers instead (i.e. Replace your -1.0f : 1.0f range with 0 : let's say, 10K).

Comment: I'm still at a loss about why you think it will produce duplicates. Even if duplicate values are entered it will be different because it also relies on the count in the actual table. Also, if I were to convert floats to integers, I'd run out of integers eventually, right? Even then, why would I use integers in the first place? Really this question is about finding nearly the same value in a `Dictionary` or some other C# generic; I appreciate your thought into it though.

Comment: If you don't take my word for it (duplicates), please refer to this article: http://www.beosil.com/download/CollisionDetectionHashing_VMV03.pdf (authors broke this algorithm down - while very good, it's still not 100% reliable). As per finite number of integers - correct, you would. But again, you can't have both - it's either your hashing algorithm to prevent colisions *or* proximity detection. Which leads to my first suggestion - please re-consider hashing again, because at this point, what you're asking is impossible (at least based purely on the hash value).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27040/discussion-between-user81572-and-piotr-justyna)

Answer (score 0):

The `Dictionary` class does not allow key collisions, so if you want multiple vectors to be associated with the same spatial hash (i.e. they get stored in the same bucket) you need to store lists of vectors rather than individuals.  Essentially you're storing your own buckets in the dictionary:

```
Dictionary<float, List<Vector3>> Buckets;
```

Next, you need to make sure that your spatial hash function returns the *same* value for every item which needs to be in the same bucket.  With that in mind you might be better off using an integer as your spatial hash.

Finally, in order to get similar items from the dictionary, you're going to have to use the following steps:

1. Determine the bounding box for getting similar items (e.g. <X-delta,
   Y-delta, Z-delta>, <X+delta, Y+delta, Z+delta>)
2. Iterate over all buckets which potentially intersect with the bounding box

   1. For each intersecting bucket, calculate the spatial hash for a point inside the bucket and use the dictionary to get the list of items in the bucket
   2. Add items from the bucket to the list of results

The above is potentially a lot of unnecessary work if your bucket size is small relative to your bounding box.  If that's the case then you should consider using a different data structure such as an octree.

Comment: While this sounds like an ideal solution, please remember that *Vector3* consist of float values. What you are suggesting is storing all possible and discrete vectors in each bucket, which is far from feasible and *will* prove to be an overkill if you implement it anyway (even for very small 3D spaces).

Answer (score 0):

In order for a `Dictionary` to work, every item must be assigned a bucket, such that every item may be blindly assumed to be non-equivalent to any item which is in a different bucket.  As such, it is not possible to use a `Dictionary` directly to locate objects which are near to a given point, since such objects might fall into more than one bucket.

If you want to be able to locate all objects which are strictly less than half a unit away from a given point, I would suggest that you assign buckets combinations of integer coordinates, and then place each point in each of the (typically eight) buckets whose coordinates represent either the next larger or next smaller integer compared to the point in question.  To find if a collection contains a point which is strictly less than half a unit away from a given point, look in the bucket for the nearest point.

Depending upon the density of the points in question, it may be helpful to use a coarser grid, in which case many objects would only need to be stored in a single bucket.  The key requirement is that every point must be stored in every bucket that could be "nearest" to any point that it should match.